# Parse.com on tvOS with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, tvos

I have an iOS app that uses Parse.com with Cocoapods. I would like to create a version of the app for tvOS but I am not sure how to install Parse for both the iOS app and tvOS. Is it possible or does Parse not support tvOS yet?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about cocoapods, but according to this Github issue on their official iOS/OS X framework, it should be working if you pull down their code. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/250

Comment: Do I use the same Podfile as I am using for my iOS app or do I create another one for the Apple TV app? Thanks

Comment: Tom Coomer - The github thread is suggesting to use:

pod 'Parse', :git => 'git@github.com:ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git', :branch => 'nlutsenko.tvos.podtest'

as your tvOS target in the Podfile